# How to copy & paste a TabPage in the Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have an existing `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage` that I want to duplicate, not programmatically, but in the Designer. In the Designer, I select the TabPage, right-click select Copy, right-click again and select Paste and I get this error:

> Cannot add component of type TabControl to container of type
>   TabControl.

[image: rightClick]

[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually copying the TabPage, you're copying the TabControl. Don't select the TabPage by clicking its tab/title, select it by clicking on any empty space inside the TabPage. Pay attention to the Properties sidebar. It should change to say "tabPage1 System.Windows.Forms.TabPage" when you have the correct control selected. Use Ctrl+C at that point, then click on the outer part (any tab, or the empty space to the right of the tabs) to select the TabControl and paste into it.

Comment: You are correct. The trick is to right-click around until you see the name of the thing you want to copy in the popup menu and then select it. Then do ctrl-c. Then click on the TabControl, then ctrl-v.